# jQuery Hide and Go Seek

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have what is proving a bit of a complex series of `div`s that I need to hide and show based on how a user answers questions.

Basically, the user is presented with a question. When they answer the question, they are presented with content based on how they answer that consists of a title and description. The current question is then hidden, and they should be then presented with the next question. When they answer the next question, the previous description should be hidden and the next title and description should be shown. This continues until all the questions are answered.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div id="q-1" class="question-group row">
        <div class="question-wrap">
            <p>question 1?</p>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="q1-yes" class="reason-wrap">
            <div class="reason">
                <h2><span class="number">1</span>reason 1</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="reason-desc">
                <p>description</p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="q1-no" class="reason-wrap">
            <div class="reason">
                <h2><span class="number">1</span>reason 1</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="reason-desc">
                <p>description</p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="q-2" class="question-group row">
        <div class="question-wrap">
            <p>question 2?</p>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="no"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="q2-yes" class="reason-wrap">
            <div class="reason">
                <h2><span class="number">2</span>reason 2</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="reason-desc">
                <p>description</p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="q2-yes" class="reason-wrap">
            <div class="reason">
                <h2><span class="number">2</span>reason 2</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="reason-desc">
                <p>description</p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

my js/jquery looks like this: (I've commented what I can't seem to get working correctly.)

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var desc = ('#'+$(this).attr("name")+'-'+$(this).val()); //matching div to display for this question 
    $(desc).toggle(); //show div for this question
    $(this).closest('.question-wrap').hide(); //hide this question
    $(this).parent().next('.question-wrap').show(); //show next question NOT WORKING
    //??? hide only the .reason-desc that is currently showing when next question is answered
});
```

and demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMJZLK

Comment: The `.next()` function only looks at immediate siblings.

Comment: .nextAll() will that work?

Comment: The problem is that your ".question-wrap" elements are nested inside the "question-group", so they're not siblings at all. You have to go up (like with `.parent(".question-group")`) then find the `.next(".question-group")` and then `.find(".question-wrap")` from there.

Comment: Also note that `$(this).attr("name") + '-' + $(this).val()` can be written as `this.name + '-' + this.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's my best attempt:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  var desc = ('#' + $(this).attr("name") + '-' + $(this).val()); //matching div to display for this question 
  $(desc).toggle(); //show div for this question
  $(this).closest('.question-wrap').hide()
    .parent().next().show().end().prev().find('.reason-desc').hide()
});
```

```css
.question-group:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}

.reason-wrap {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.reason h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.reason-desc p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div id="q-1" class="question-group row">
      <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>question 1?</p>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no"> No
            </label>
      </div>
      <div id="q1-yes" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">1</span>reason 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="q1-no" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">1</span>reason 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="q-2" class="question-group row">
      <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>question 2?</p>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="no"> No
            </label>
      </div>
      <div id="q2-yes" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">2</span>reason 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="q2-no" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">2</span>reason 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="q-3" class="question-group row">
      <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>question 3?</p>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="no"> No
            </label>
      </div>
      <div id="q3-yes" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">3</span>reason 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="q3-no" class="reason-wrap">
        <div class="reason">
          <h2><span class="number">3</span>reason 3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="reason-desc">
          <p>description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Also, note that you probably meant to put `<div id="q2-no">` instead of having two versions of `<div id="q2-yes">`.

Comment: I'm trying to hide the current question when answered and hide current reason-desc when next question is answered. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: I fixed the demo so that only the `.reason-desc` are hidden. Hope that helps.

Comment: getting really close, however, this doesn't hide the reason-desc when i add a 3rd set!

Comment: That's strange! Let me update the demo and take a look.

Comment: I just added a third question to the demo, and it still is working fine for me. Can you check if mine works on your browser and then compare the HTML with your own updates?